# Регистрация видимых элементов при скролле страницы только один раз

Tags: javascript

На странице есть список элементов:

```
<article class='post' id='1'></article>
<article class='post' id='2'></article>
<article class='post' id='3'></article>
<article class='post' id='n'></article>
```

Необходимо совершать действие с каждым элементом, когда он появляется в видимой области окна. Например, увеличивать просмотр в базе (простым Ajax-запросом).

Делаю так:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var $e = $('.post'); // все элементы post
    $e.each(function(index) { // перебираем
        var $window = $(window);
        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + 20 + $window.height();
        var elemTop = $e.eq(index).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $e.eq(index).height();
        if (elemTop > docViewTop && elemBottom < docViewBottom) {
            //получаем id видимого элемента и тут выполняем запрос
            console.log($e.eq(index).attr('id'));
        }
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что при событии `scroll` условие может выполниться сто раз, 
если скроллить контейнер на месте. В нашем случае пока мы скроллим этот элемент, мы получаем следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно выполнить условие один раз, чтобы можно было выполнить один запрос при попадании контейнера в видимую область браузера?

Comment: Храните для каждого элемента флаг (можно с помощью data-атрибута). Если вам нужно вообще только один Ajax-запрос на один элемент отправлять, то ставите флаг в `true` после отправки, а перед отправкой проверяете значение этого флага. Если же нужно делать повторный Ajax-запрос если элемент скрылся и снова показался, то тогда нужно флаг сбрасывать в `false` в тот момент как элемент перестаёт быть видимым

Comment: Спасибо большое за дельный совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расставляйте на просмотренных элементах флаг, например seen

```
<article class='post' id='1' seen="true"></article>
<article class='post' id='2' seen="true"></article>
<article class='post' id='3'></article>
<article class='post' id='n'></article>
```

При попытке скрипта отправить сообщение о том что элемент просмотрен смотрите если флаг seen уже выставлен, то отменяется отсылку, если не выставлен, то отправляете на сервер и добавляете `seen="true"`.